# Create embedded document on object creation in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Let's say I have these:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :email, type: String
  embeds_many :auths

  attr_protected :name, :email
end

class Auth
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :provider
  field :uid

  embedded_in :user

  attr_protected :provider, :uid
end
```

I create a new user using this method:

```
  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      user.auths.build(provider: auth['provider'], uid: auth['uid'])
      if auth['info']
        user.name = auth['info']['name'] || ''
        user.email = auth['info']['email'] || ''
      end
    end
  end
```

However, when I look into my database, the result is this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("517f5f425aca0fbf3a000007"),
  "name" : "User",
  "email" : "mail@example.com",
  "auths" : [
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("517f5f425aca0fbf3a000008")
    }
  ]
}
```

What do I have to do in order to actually save the data provided? The `uid` and the `provider` are always properly in the `auth` array, I checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently attributes are just skipped since that's what you tell Rails

Either change:

```
attr_protected :provider, :uid
```

to:

```
attr_accessible :provider, :uid
```

or proceed as follows:

```
user.auths.build.tap do |user_auth|
  user_auth.provider = auth['provider']
  user_auth.uid      = auth['uid']
end
```

Comment: That's what you get for following tutorials that don't explain all of their stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  create! do |user|
    auth = Auth.build(provider: auth['provider'], uid: auth['uid'])
    if auth['info']
      user.name = auth['info']['name'] || ''
      user.email = auth['info']['email'] || ''
    end
    user.auths << auth
  end
end
```